# Why does my enum method in Java always return the last values response?

Tags: java, enums

I'm currently attempting a minor thing in Java: A small diceroller based on an enum.

The idea is to be able to call a method that, based on the value of the enum, returns a dice roll.

My code looks like this:

```
private static int result;

private static int randIntMinMax(int min, int max){
    Random rand = new Random();

    return (rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min);
}

static {
    D2.result = randIntMinMax(1, 2);
    D3.result = randIntMinMax(1, 3);
    D4.result = randIntMinMax(1, 4);
    D6.result = randIntMinMax(1, 6);
    D8.result = randIntMinMax(1, 8);
    D10.result = randIntMinMax(1, 10);
    D12.result = randIntMinMax(1, 12);
    D20.result = randIntMinMax(1, 20);
    D100.result = randIntMinMax(1, 100);
}

public static int Roll(){

    return result;
}

public static int Roll(int amount){
    int added = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < amount; i++){

        added += Roll();
    }

    return added;
}
```

When I do something like this though:

```
Dice DSix = Dice.D6;
int example = DSix.Roll();
```

I always get the value of a `.Roll();` of the D100, the last one in the row.

How come?

Comment: See also https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`result` is a static variable which is associated with the class so always has the last assigned value. Use an instance variable instead and make the corresponding methods instance methods.

```
public int getRollResult() {

    return result;
}
```